# Subfloat Caption left aligned

Tags: floats, lncs, subfig

I would like to create a figure with a left-aligned subfloat caption as the following:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Resource Owner Password \hspace{\textwidth}Credential Grant]{
        \missingfigure[figwidth=0.5\textwidth]{Testing a long text string}
        \label{fig:pwd_grant}
    }
    \subfloat[Client Credential Grant]{
        \missingfigure[figwidth=0.5\textwidth]{Testing a long text string}
        \label{fig:client_grant}
    }
    \caption{grants}
    \label{fig:auth_impl_grant}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(if you compile now the example you will see the actual problem with the caption and why I would wish to have it left aligned)

using the **subfig** package with documenttype **lncs**
currently the caption is in block mode - means tex spreads it over the complete available distance. This looks pretty crappy to me...

Thank you very much in advance.

@Peiffap
Thanks to your suggestion I was able to create an example that worked for me with left aligned caption, but also in height aligned caption, it looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{
        \subcaptionbox{Resource Owner Password\\ Credential Grant}[.47\linewidth]{
            \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{Testing a text string}
            \label{fig:auth_grant}
        }
        \hspace*{2cm}
        \subcaptionbox{Client Credential Grant}[.47\linewidth]{
            \centering
            \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{Testing a text string}
            \label{fig:impl_grant}
        }
    }
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:auth_impl_grant}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

for some odd reason, when I put this into overleaf with the missing figure placeholder it looks odd, still locally it works totally fine.

Comment: I hope the code snippet is now completly functional

Comment: Why `\hspace{\textwidth}`?

Comment: To create a linebreak in a caption, I would like to split the caption over two lines that it doesn't collide with the caption of figure (b)

Comment: That will definitely cause a warning. You have a much simpler command: \\

Comment: this doesn't compile on my machine, I mean of course I know \\ but I already googled this workaround to be able to produce a linebreak in a caption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package, I could make the following.

[image]

This is the code I used to generate that (admittedly, I didn't have the `llncs` package installed, so I changed that out for `article`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
        \centering
        \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{Testing a long text string}
        \caption{Resource Owner Password \\ Credential Grant}
        \label{fig:pwd_grant}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
        \centering
        \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{Testing a long text string}
        \caption{Client Credential Grant}
        \label{fig:client_grant}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{grants}
    \label{fig:auth_impl_grant}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Do note however that `subcaption` and `subfig` are not compatible! For what it's worth though, `subfig` was getting pretty obsolete last time I checked, while `subcaption` fixes some of its flaws (compatibility with `hyperref` being a big one).

### Edit

After some more work, OP went with the following code.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{
        \subcaptionbox{Resource Owner Password\\ Credential Grant}[.47\linewidth]{
            \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{Testing a text string}
            \label{fig:auth_grant}
        }
        \hspace*{2cm}
        \subcaptionbox{Client Credential Grant}[.47\linewidth]{
            \centering
            \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{Testing a text string}
            \label{fig:impl_grant}
        }
    }
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:auth_impl_grant}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using **subfig** because **springers llncs** and **subcaption** are **not compatible**

Comment: @SilenceandI. Have you tried using `\captionsetup{compatibility=false}`?

Comment: not yet, didn't know this exists

Comment: @SilenceandI. Tell me if it works, I will update my answer in case it does.

Comment: thank you very much - I added to my question the changes I made to your suggestion to get a properly formated version of it :) - feel free to update your answer